Disabling err handler
I have run the following code in VBA to disable error checking for values in text format, but it does not work. I am still getting a green triangle in the upper left corner of the cell. The exact same code worked fine until about November 2023, but on December 25, it no longer works. Excel is the latest version (2403). Does anyone know how to remedy this? Thank you in advance for your help.
Sub error check ()
Dim cl As Range
For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  If cl.Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = False Then
     cl.Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True
  End If
Next
End Sub


It is possible that another warning also invoked in the cell.

Click on the green triangle and check the error that you are getting...
